# Get day from date in jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How to get date " day " from date selected by user. I dont want current date day

```js
var selected_from_date = $("#startDate").val();
var d = new Date(selected_from_date);
var day = d.getDate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="startTime" id="startDate" value="27.02.2021" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#startTime" />
```

Comment: Your JS code is correct, although you possibly need `getDay()` instead of `getDate()`. The issue you have is because the Date object constructor works with dates in ISO or US format only. You need to change the value of the input to `2021-02-27` or `02/27/2021`

Comment: `getDay` is not working

Comment: Right, for the reason I explained in the rest of the comment.

Comment: I am new in javascript can you please help me how to change date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your date format (selected_from_date) is:

```
"mm.dd.yyyy"
```

You can work with this.

```js
var selected_from_date = $("#startDate").val();
var day = selected_from_date.split(".")[1];
$("#startDate").val(day);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="startTime" id="startDate" value="27.02.2021" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#startTime" />
```